# Unable to Connect IIS Manager Console

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-8

[image: Not Able to connect IIS Manager this Error Occured]

When i am open IIS manager this Error come. Also tried to run as Administrator and also tried to disable IIS service from "Turn Windows Features On and Off"

Comment: Start > Run > inetmgr.exe

Comment: @VDWWD thanks for response but same Error.

Comment: The dialog asks for valid user name and password. Do you reallly have the correct information there?

Comment: @LexLi but for this i Didnt add any credentials

Comment: You have to click OK and then Cancel. Remove this server connection to VOSTRO, and then create a new connection with valid user credentials. Sounds like the previous connection information stored is corrupt.